# Do arrays with gaps in their indices entail any benefits that compensate their disadvantages

Tags: javascript, arrays

In Javascript arrays may have gaps in their indices, which should not be confused with elements that are simply `undefined`:

```
var a = new Array(1), i;
a.push(1, undefined);

for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (i in a) {
    console.log("set with " + a[i]);
  } else {
    console.log("not set");
  }
}

// logs:
// not set
// set with 1
// set with undefined
```

Since these gaps corrupt the length property I'm not sure, if they should be avoided whenever possible. If so, I would treat them as edge case and not by default:

```
// default:
function head(xs) {
  return xs[0];
}

// only when necessary:
function gapSafeHead(xs) {
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < xs.length; i++) {
    if (i in xs) {
      return xs[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Besides the fact that `head` is very concise, another advantage is that it can be used on all array-like data types. `head` is just a single simple example. If such gaps need to be considered throughout the code, the overhead should be significantly.

Comment: I, for once, avoid gaps like the plague.

Comment: If they are indeed indices and use "classical" array, then yes, it makes sense to avoid gaps.  There would be nothing wrong with gaps when you treat your arrays as objects with numeric properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely to come up in any language that overloads hash tables to provide something that colloquially is called an "array". PHP, Lua and JavaScript are three such languages. If you depend on strict sequential numeric array behavior, then it will be an inconvenience for you. More generally, the behavior provides conveniences as well.

Here's a classic algorithm question: to delete a member from the middle of a data structure, which data structure is "better": A linked list or an array?

You're supposed to say "linked list", because deleting a node from a linked list doesn't require you to shift the rest of the array down one index. But linked lists have other pitfalls, so is there another data structure we can use? You can use a sparse array*.

In many languages that provide this hashy type of arrays, removing any arbitrary member of the array will change the length. Unfortunately, JavaScript does not change the length, so you lose out a little there. But nevertheless, the array is "shorter", at least from the `Object.keys` perspective.

*Many [sparse arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array) are implemented using linked lists, so don't apply this too generally. In these languages, though, they're hash tables with predictable ordered numeric keys.

Comment: Thanks for the theoretical background and the given example. Can you name a js lib that uses arrays in that way (as sparse arrays)? That would help!

Comment: Not specifically, but I will note that sparse arrays are covered by both [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/9781449393854/ch07s03.html) and [Dr. Axel Rauschmayer's excellent blog](http://www.2ality.com/2012/06/dense-arrays.html?m=1). You see, calling out the sparse array in a lib would be odd, like saying "here is a list comprehension" in a Python lib–it's just a feature of the language. If it's used, it's used as a matter of course.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, the question is a subjective one, but I argue that the gaps should certainly be avoided, if possible. Arrays are special Javascript objects with very specific purposes. You can totally hack on arrays, manipulate the length property, add properties with keys other than numbers (e.g myArray["foo"] = "bar"), but these mostly devolve into antipatterns. If you need some special form of pseudo-array, you can always just code it yourself with a regular object. After all, typeof [] === "object"

It's not like gaps inherently break your code, but I would avoid pursuing them intentionally.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: If no one can show examples, which illustrate benefits of arrays with gaps that outweigh their obvious disadvantages, then my question is answered